# Knockout - foreach: Change button color on click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a table listing elements from an observable array. Where I am running into difficulty is, that when the button is click on an item that the button changes color and changes to the value of 'selected', if the button is clicked again it reverse. I have successfully as a test bound the button text color to a property in the current $data which works. When I click and change the property value nothing happens.

It is the button tag that the problem arises.

Sample Code:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: slcs ">
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: slc"></td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control input-sm runinputs" data-bind="selectedOptions: $data.pbr, optionsCaption: 'Choose'">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control input-sm runinputs" data-bind="selectedOptions: $data.of, optionsCaption: 'Choose'">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control input-sm runinputs" data-bind="selectedOptions: $data.lotsize, optionsCaption: 'Choose'">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-bind="click: $data.status = 0,  click: function() { $parent.selectSetting($data); }, style: { color: $data.status = 0 ? 'red' : 'black' }">Select</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You cannot attach several binding handlers of the same type to a single element. Your button has two click bindings.

Comment: Why don't you have entire logic inside single click function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your parent model looks like, or what `selectSetting` is supposed to accomplish, but I did note that in

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-bind="click: $data.status = 0,  click: function() { $parent.selectSetting($data); }, style: { color: $data.status = 0 ? 'red' : 'black' }">
```

your first `click` binding sets the item's status to `0`, but won't toggle it. So that's one problem.

Another problem is in the `style` section, where you have `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, it was the = instead of == that was the issue.